# How to access Response Headers in the get api call - Angular 7

Tags: angular

I'm trying to download the .csv file coming from the backend with specific filename. How can i access the filename from the api Response Header using Angular 7

[image]

my service (api call):

```
 public getDownloadFile(masterDistributorId: number, runDate: string) {
    return this.http.get
      (`${environment.apiUrl}command-center/report/download/? 
         masterDistributorId=${masterDistributorId}&runDate=${runDate}`, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'application/csv'),
        responseType: 'blob',
        observe: 'response'
      }
      );
  }
```

my subscribe call:

```
 public Download(row: DistributorItem) {
    console.log(row.masterDistributorId);
    console.log(this.RunDate);
    this.CommandService.getDownloadFile(row.masterDistributorId, this.RunDate).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res.headers);
      this.SaveFile(res);
    });
  }
```

Comment: showConfigResponse() {
  this.configService.getConfigResponse()
    // resp is of type `HttpResponse<Config>`
    .subscribe(resp => {
      // display its headers
      const keys = resp.headers.keys();
      this.headers = keys.map(key =>
        `${key}: ${resp.headers.get(key)}`);

      // access the body directly, which is typed as `Config`.
      this.config = { ... resp.body };
    });
}

Visit https://angular.io/guide/http for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Get response header value: [Reading the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

```
key = 'content-disposition';
contentDisposition = response.headers.get(key)
```

Split header content disposition string: [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
filename = contentDisposition.split("=")[1];
```

Your case:

```
    this.CommandService.getDownloadFile(row.masterDistributorId, this.RunDate).subscribe(res => {
      let filename = res.headers.get('content-disposition').split("=")[1];
      console.log(filename);
      this.SaveFile(res);
    });
```

Comment: But I'm getting null in the filename using this  `let filename = res.headers.get('content-disposition').split("=")[1];` But I'm getting content-disposition in networks tab .

Comment: Try to use this key '`C`ontent-`D`isposition'.